# is there any mail server in microsoft server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

is there any mail server in microsoft server 2008.

Answer (score 2):

yes, there is, but is very basic

I suggest to use [hmailserver](http://www.hmailserver.com/)

Comment: It is basic, but it still works well if the only purpose is to send mails. If it is used only for a web application to send mails for "I forgot my password, reset it please", Windows SMTP service is fine.

Answer (score 1):

The SMTP (mail) server is still there in Windows Server 2008, but it is less obvious to install and to configure it since Windows Server 2008 ships with IIS7, and SMTP server is configured through IIS6 Manager.

### Installing the SMTP service

To install the SMTP service, go to Server Manager and expand Roles and Features.

In Roles, right-click on *Web server (IIS)*, and click on "Ad Role Services". Add *IIS 6 Metabase Compatibility* and *IIS 6 Management Console* (both in *Management Tools* -> *IIS 6 Management Compatibility*).

In Features, open *Add Features Wizard* and search for *SMTP Server* in the list.

### Configuring SMTP service

To configure SMTP service, start *Internet Information Services (IIS) 6.0 Manager* (typing "IIS" in start menu works well). In the tree on the left, you will find your server, and inside, *[SMTP Virtual Server #1]*.

Do not expand it, but rather right-click on it, and choose "Properties". You will find everything you need here.